# How do I import this module in python

Tags: python, pycharm

[image showing directories and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpuEr.png)

I'mm trying to import views.py
I've already tried import personal_portfolio.hello_world.views

Comment: Add `__init__.py` under `personal_portfolio` folder.

Comment: If your virtual environment is enabled, `import personal_portfolio.hello_world.views` should work (after the `__init__.py` change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using python3 you need to do a relative import instead of absolute so change `import views` to `from . import views`

and in django it is always good to import with whole relative path Eg: `from hello_world import views`

Comment: While this approach works, you don't necessarily _need_ to do a relative import. Absolute imports work fine too.